# Field accessibility in Triggers

Tags: trigger

We are encountering an unexpected exception when using a field in a AfterInsert trigger:

```
execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field
```

We are not performing any query in this case, what are the rules around triggers and fields accessibility? We were unable to find the relevant documentation

Comment: Can you post your code in this question

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared the code, this is my thoughts.

Suppose if I write a trigger like this, where it is trying to pull BillingStreet from the Account record using relationship then you will get that exception

> execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
        {
            String billingStreet = caseObj.Account.BillingStreet;
        }
    }
}
```

For that scenario you need to query BillingStreet from Account object passing accountIds.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
        {
            accountIds.add(caseObj.AccountId);
        }
    }

    List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id, BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE Id:accountIds];
    //use the BillingStreet loop through the list

}
```

Comment: We are not walking the relationship, we access only the id, such as caseObj.Account

Comment: If you try to access the Id then caseObj.AccountId instead of caseObj.Account

Comment: We had a custom field on a custom object which is called Account__c and the code failed with that error